# AutoMapper - Central place to create all mappings in a code library

Tags: c#, automapper

I know that if I was using AutoMapper in an MVC project, I could add my mappings to the AppDomain. I'm creating APIs would like to have all this information in one location in the API, hidden from the consummer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into AutoMapper profiles?

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/15/automapper-profiles.aspx

Comment: I should have seen that. Thanks,